# Trouble creating a data boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, valueerror

I'm trying to extract variables from a data spreadsheet to form a boxplot which looks like this:

```py
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd

 pulserate = pd.read_csv("PulseNew.csv")
 ran_yes = pulserate[pulserate["Ran"] == "yes"]
 ran_no = pulserate[pulserate["Ran"] == "no"]
 ry = ran_yes
 rn = ran_no
 ran_data = [ry, rn]
 plt.boxplot(ran_data)
 plt.show()
```

However, when I do this I end up receiving this error:

`ValueError: X must have 2 or fewer dimensions`

Upon seeing that, I tried inserting these lines instead:

```py
pulserate = pd.read_csv("PulseNew.csv")
ran_yes = pulserate[pulserate["Ran"] == "yes"]
ran_no = pulserate[pulserate["Ran"] == "no"]
subset = pulserate[(pulserate["Ran"] ==  "yes") & (pulserate["Ran"] == "no")]
plt.boxplot(subset)
plt.show()
```

While this did not result in an error, all I got was an empty graph. For context, I'm a beginning Python programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You must extract the column that you want to plot from each data frame and pass it as a 1D array:

```
pulserate = pd.read_csv("PulseNew.csv")
ran_yes = pulserate[pulserate["Ran"] == "yes"]
ran_no = pulserate[pulserate["Ran"] == "no"]
ry = ran_yes["Pulse"] # extract the Pulse column from ran_yes
rn = ran_no["Pulse"] # extract the Pulse column from ran_no
ran_data = [ry, rn] # create a list of 1D arrays
plt.boxplot(ran_data) 
plt.show()
```

Try this way and give me the result please.

Comment: All I get now when I type that in is KeyError: 'Pulse'

Comment: you are getting a KeyError: 'Pulse' because the column name 'Pulse' does not exist in your DataFrame pulserate. it was an example I had written and you should specify this value based on the desired column.

Comment: I specified my desired column which is "Ran" which resulted in  this error: 

TypeError: ufunc 'divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''